# Problems with installing gevent for python3 on mac

Tags: python-3.x, gevent

I tried to install it:

```
sudo pip3 install git+git://github.com/fantix/gevent.git
```

I got the following error:

```
14 warnings and 1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Looking at the trace back message, here is the error:

```
/usr/bin/clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -U__llvm__ -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -
DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.macosx-
10.6-intel-3.4/libev -Ilibev -
I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -c gevent/gevent.corecext.c 
-o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.4/gevent/gevent.corecext.o

gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3:33: error: expected identifier or '('
/* Generated by Cython 0.21 */ */
```

I tried to debug but no luck. Anyone had similar problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

```
gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3:33: error: expected identifier or '('
/* Generated by Cython 0.21 */ */
```

I just deleted the */ in that file and it works. No idea how this is generated in the first place.